# Duplicate Error on adding data in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

I am trying to insert data in mongoDB document but I am getting duplicate error in it.

[image: Code]

While defining the schema, I have given the value of "role" as default:"customer".
But on adding data with different number, i am getting this error.

Following is the schema defined:
[image: Schema]

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the collection have unique index on the column.

```
db.customers.getIndexes()
```

here you will get unique index on userName. drop it

It will return all the indexes. If it have unique: true then drop it and then insert records.

OR just use

```
db.customers.dropIndex('username_1')
```

**It's not the error because of mobilenumber. it's because of username. you are trying to insert multiple username with null value which is violating unique rule.**

Comment: Hey thanks buddy, its working now.
But can you tell why this error came up?
I mean from where did this username thing came up and became a unique index?

Comment: it's because you was creating two username with null value.  You might have created this field with this index but now this field is no more in schema but it's index was still there.Accept answer if it worked. cheers!!